# La app no se ejecuta flutterflow

Tags: flutter, ejecutar

Estoy desarrollando una app en flutterflow pero al momento de darle en ejecutar me suelta un error, no sé leerlo y por eso pido su ayuda para arreglar este error, flutterflow tampoco me suelta ningún error, adjunto la imágen.

[image: Aquí es donde está el problema pero no se ubicarlo]

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Considera añadir el código relevante que genera este mensaje durante la compilación. Y de paso, considera añadir ese log como texto para que lo podamos leer correctamente. Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).